# How to set product Limit in cms page in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cms-pages

I have created one cms page and in this page I have added below code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/view/products.phtml"}}
```

> products.phtml

```
<?php

        $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                            ->setPageSize(20)
                            ->setCurPage(1);




    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')) {

    $_parent_id = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId();
    }
    $_itemCollection = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlistItemCollection();
    if($_itemCollection) {
    foreach($_itemCollection as $wish) {
        $wish_product = $wish->getProduct();
        $wishlist_array[$wish_product->getId()] = $wish_product->getId();
    }
    }


?>

<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="alert-error fade in" style="<?php if($_parent_id == 17) echo 'display:none';?>">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><img style="width:24px;height:24px;margin-left:10px" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/Items.png'); ?>"></a>
  <?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">

    <div class="page-title" >

    <?php 
        //$_product = $this->getProduct();
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')) {
            $_parent=Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getName();
            if ($_parent != 'Main'):
              echo $_parent;
              echo ' > ';
          endif;
            $_category=Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
            echo $_category; 

          }
    ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = 3; ?>
            <ul class="products-grid unstyled thubmnails row-fluid">
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $pro): ?>
    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pro->getId());?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif ?>
            <li class="product-item item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> quick<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
                <div class=" productgrid" style="margin-bottom:15px;width:300px;height:300px;background: url('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(370); ?>');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;">
                    <a class="emptylink" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                        <?php if(in_array($_product->getSku(), $_gift_card_array ) === false): ?>
                        <div class="emptylinkdiv" style="position: relative">&nbsp;<div class="quickview hidden-phone" name="modal" onclick="jQuery('#simplemodal-container').show();  quickview(<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>, false); return false;"></div></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid listing-name-price">
                    <div class="lising_product_name"><a class="product-name" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></div>
                    <span class="secret-sku hide"><?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?></span>
                    <div class="listing_product_price"><span class="product-price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?></span></div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php
        /* @var $toolbar Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar */
        // get toolbars limits - overrides default pager limit
        $toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getAvailableLimit();

        /* @var $pager Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'bootstrapped.standalone.pager');

        // set limit - uses category's instead of default pager's (10-20-50)
        $pager->setAvailableLimit($toolbar);
        // need to set collection
        $pager->setCollection($_productCollection);
        //set custom template
        $pager->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/pager.phtml');
        echo $pager->toHtml();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultoutheight = -1;
    jQuery(".listing-name-price").each(function(index) {
        if(jQuery(this).outerHeight() > defaultoutheight)   
        defaultoutheight = jQuery(this).outerHeight();  
    });
    jQuery(".listing-name-price").height(defaultoutheight);
});
</script>
```

I have set product limit to 20 and set first page as a current page
but the issue is that I can see 20 products in first page
and these same 20 products are repeating in next page and so on. So in short I got same 20 products in all the pages

Currently I have 8000 products in my website and I loaded all these products in above file(cms page).

Keep in mind that I want only 20 products per page.I already have pagination this cms page but it is not working

So how can I display all 8000 products(20 per page) in all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Use a classic category to display your requirements. You can set page size in configuration and the liste comes with pagination out of the box!

Comment: Can you write more detailed answer?